# C#: Change the resource file without re-building?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resources, internationalization, resx

For an Asp.Net MVC 3 application, I will a use resources files to store my I18N( [How-to](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx) ).

It's not me which will translate all fields in all languages, I just have to create in one language and create empty language files for the two other languages. And in the implementation I will use those three files.

So for the development I've not any problem, but after I've created the website, it's the customer which will translate all those fields. I found a great app which allows to translate from one resx to one other ( [SimpleResxEditor](http://simpleresxeditor.blogspot.com/) ). But now, how can the customer change this resx file in the asp.net website without visual studio? Is there a way to specify in visual studio that we use a "not-embedded" resource file, and changing this file will takes an immediate effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the ressource file via `resgen` first:

```
resgen InternationalResources.resx
```

Output is a .resources file.

After the you have to link the ressource to the assembly via `al.exe`:

```
al.exe 
/t:lib 
/culture:de-AT 
/out:"\LocalizeableConsole.resources.dll" 
/embed:InternationalResources.resources,LocalizeableConsole.InternationalResources.de-AT.resources 
/template:"LocalizeableConsole.exe"
/keyf:KeyFile.snk
```

Comment: doesn't this actually put the .resources file *into* the assembly?

Comment: Yes it does. But the Assembly does not have to be recompiled but has the new language strings integrated.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid this processing? by letting those resx file uncompiled?

Comment: I did not find any. This is the way we do it. We put the commands into a batch file and the customer executes if necessary.

Comment: And with what those two tools(resgen and al) are provided?

Comment: They are provided with the .NET Framework SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx